# When (and how) do executors yield control back to the event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am trying to wrap my head around `asyncio` for the first time, and I think I've got a basic grasp on coroutines & how to await their corresponding objects. Now, I've encountered `AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor`, and the concept makes sense in the abstract (no pun intended): you have some blocking operation, so you kick it off to a thread so that the main thread (i.e. the thread running the main event loop) can continue its work.

The thing that I do not understand is how the event loop manages context switches between coroutines (cooperative multitasking), and this newly created thread (preemptive multitasking). As I understand it, every coroutine is `await`ed, and the act of `await`ing that coroutine yields control back to the event loop. This allows the event loop to start running another coroutine. But threads are not cooperative in this manner -- there is some other scheduler (I believe in your OS, but that may be wrong) that schedules when threads run, and threads can be stopped at any point in their execution. Additionally, why do you even call `run_in_executor` on the event loop? Shouldn't the newly created thread be completely separate from the thread that is running the event loop in order to allow for the concurrency that we're looking for?

My only guess at what could be happening is that since `run_in_executor` returns a coroutine (which is also a little confusing -- how do you get a coroutine out of a thread?), `await`ing this coroutine causes a context switch in the underlying thread, but I really have no idea how you could implement something like that.

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track with your understanding of coroutines and asyncio. Let's break down the interaction between the event loop, coroutines, and threads.

[`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) is a method provided by the event loop to run a function in a separate thread (or process) and return an [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-awaitable) object (specifically, an [`asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future)) that represents the eventual result of the function. This is useful when you have a blocking operation that you want to offload from the main thread running the event loop. You're correct that threads are scheduled by the OS and can be stopped at any point in their execution, making them preemptive multitasking.

When you call `run_in_executor` on the event loop, the event loop creates a new thread (or uses an existing thread in a thread pool) to execute the function you've provided. This new thread is indeed separate from the main thread running the event loop. The reason you call `run_in_executor` on the event loop is that it allows the event loop to manage the concurrency and coordinate the result of the blocking operation with the coroutines it's already handling.

Now, let's talk about the coroutine-like object that `run_in_executor` returns. When you `await` this object, you are not awaiting the actual thread, but rather an `asyncio.Future` object that represents the result of the function you've run in the separate thread. The `Future` object is a placeholder for the eventual result of the computation. By awaiting the `Future`, the event loop can continue to execute other coroutines until the result is ready.

When the function you've run in the separate thread completes, the separate thread updates the `Future` object with the result or any exception that occurred during execution. The event loop, which is monitoring the status of the `Future`, sees that the result is ready and schedules the coroutine that was awaiting the `Future` to resume execution. This way, the event loop manages the concurrency between the coroutines and the threads without needing to context-switch the threads themselves.

In summary, `run_in_executor` is called on the event loop because it allows the event loop to manage concurrency between coroutines and threads. The coroutine-like object returned by `run_in_executor` is not a coroutine itself but an `asyncio.Future` that represents the eventual result of the blocking operation. The event loop handles the coordination of results between threads and coroutines, allowing for concurrent execution.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking that `asyncio` switches between coroutines and threads has it the wrong way around: It is `threading` that switches between `asyncio` and its executor.

---

The context switching between the two happens via the usual thread switching mechanism: The Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) regularly is handed from one thread to another.
Say `asyncio` is currently executing a coroutine, then the GIL-mechanism can pause the coroutine *at any point* and run an executor thread instead. Likewise, if an executor thread is running the GIL-mechanism may pause that thread and go back to running `asyncio` and its last coroutine instead.
This by itself is exactly the same behaviour as used for unrelated threads, or threads of different event loops, or threads of different executors.

The special "magic sauce" that `asyncio` adds is that it registers a callback for any executor thread task: [`asyncio` tells the executor](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4abfe6a14b5be5decbaa3142d9e2549cf2d86c34/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L826-L840) to [run some extra code that basically says "I am done, you can proceed"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4abfe6a14b5be5decbaa3142d9e2549cf2d86c34/Lib/asyncio/futures.py#L365-L406). This in turn triggers `asyncio` to continue running each coroutine that was waiting on the executor task.

---

Notably, almost none of this is "`async` code". Submitting a tasks, having it run concurrently, triggering an action when done are all exactly equivalent to regular `threading`/`concurrent.futures` usage. `asyncio` merely adds a thin facade in front of it so that it looks `async` for code that must `await` the thread to complete.

A simple recreating of the mechanism would use [an `asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) to signal completion, and instruct the thread to [call `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(event.set)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) when done. This makes the thread trigger the event, and thus wake up every coroutine waiting for the event.

```py
async def as_thread(_sync_call, *args, **kwargs):
    """Simple 'thread coroutine' to run blocking code"""
    # prepare an event that another thread can trigger in this event loop
    done = asyncio.Event()
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    def wrapper():
        _sync_call(*args, **kwargs)
        # this makes the thread inform the loop that it is done
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(done.set)

    # 100% regular Thread! The GIL and all other nasty thread stuff lurks here!
    threading.Thread(target=wrapper).start()
    # simply await for the thread to trigger the event when done
    await done.wait()
```

The added machinery of `run_in_executor` is mainly about bookkeeping (cancelling the task, ...) and providing a return value or exception.